# Matrix generation code simply fails, and I have no idea why

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Here is the code I have that doesn't work (sorry if it's formatted quite badly - code blocks suck):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>
#define m 10

void matrix_gen(int s, int i, int j, double matrix[s][s], int opt_strat[m][m][m]);

for (int u=0; u<s; ++u) {
    for (int v=0; v<s; ++v) {
        if (u==v) {
            matrix[u][v]=1;
        }
        if (u == s/2) {
            if (opt_strat[j][i][0]== 1) {
                if (v == m-i) {
                    matrix[u][v]=1;
                }
                else {
                    if (v==m-i+(s/2)) {
                        matrix[u][v]=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (u==(s/2)+m-i) {
            if (opt_strat[i][j][0] == 1) {
                if (v==0) {
                    matrix[u][v]=1;
                }
                else {
                    if (v==(s/2)) {
                        matrix[u][v]=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int u=0; u<m-i-1; ++u) {
    for (int v=0; v<s; ++v) {
        if (opt_strat[i][j][u]==1) {
            if (v==u+1) {
                matrix[u][v]= -0.5;
            }
            else {
                if (v==u+(s/2)+1) {
                    matrix[u][v]= -0.5;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int u=m-i; u<(s/2)-1; ++u) {
    for (int v=0; v<s; ++v) {
        if (opt_strat[j][i][u-m+i]==1) {
            if (v==u+1) {
                matrix[u][v]= -0.5;
            }
            else {
                if (v==u+1+(s/2)) {
                    matrix[u][v]= -0.5;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}



 void v_vector_gen(){


 }

 int main () {

   /* p_vector = probability vector, M the matrix and v_vector the constants in system */

int i,j,s,level=18;
int opt_strat[m][m][m]={1};
double probs[m][m][m]={0};

while (level >=0) {
    for (i=9; i>=0; --i) {
        for (j=9; j>=0; --j) {
            if (j>i) {
                continue;
            }
            if (i+j==level) {
                printf("\nSublevel %d,%d\n",i,j);

                s=2*(2*m-i-j);
                double* p = NULL;
                double* p_vector = malloc(s * sizeof *p);
                double* v_vector = malloc(s * sizeof *p);
                double (*matrix)[s] = malloc(sizeof(double[s][s]));
                //double** matrix;
//                  matrix = (double**) malloc(s * sizeof(double*));
//                  for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
//                      matrix[i] = (double*) malloc(s * sizeof(double));

            /*Use separate functions to define matrix and vector*/

                matrix_gen(s, i, j, matrix, opt_strat);

            /*Print the matrix to check*/

                for (int i=0; i<s; ++i) {
                    printf("\n\n");
                    for (int j=0; j<s; ++j) {
                        printf(" %lf ", matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    --level;
}

while (1==1) {}

return 0;
}
```

The issue is that the code in the first function, which should be altering the entries of the matrix, don't! The first if statement works, and I get an identity matrix as a result, but all the halves and minus halves that should appear always remain zero. I thought maybe the values such as (s/2)+m-i might be the problem (this isn't my algorithm! This is a group project..) but all these values should make sense for matrix entries. It seems like the code is ignoring all but the first if statement, and I have no idea why. We know the procedure above should be making the correct matrices - it has been done in python with good results - the bulk of the programming is in C however, so we tried to transport it over.

Can anybody spot what is going wrong, and prevents the matrix entries from being altered? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comparing an int to a floating type isn't a good idea `u==s/2`

Comment: @ScottyBauer u and s are both defined as integers, and s is always even, so the result would also be an integer..? (and even if not, rounded down to an integer)

Comment: Yeah it wont be rounded to an integer. The compiler will replace the `s/2` with a floating type. And floating types have rounding errors so while `s/2` could equal 4 in real math, a float may represent it as 3.999999 which obviously isn't the same as 4==4.

Comment: Well, I tried one such comparison as 2*u==s instead. It had no effect :/

Comment: Since commonly implemented floating-point arithmetic systems (such as IEEE) can represent both `4` and `2` exactly it's reasonable to expect the division of one by the other to be (floating-point) `2`. Whether that `==` the integer `2` is, perhaps, another matter

Comment: Studying this much code and finding out error manually is too tedious for anyone. Try using debugging tools like `gdb` to step through the code and find the mistake.

Comment: @ScottyBauer I don't know what compiler you are using, but mine does a simple integer division when faced with something like `s/2` - just as the C standard requires... `s/2.0` would be a different story, but as High Performance Mark pointed out, even that would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that the code in the first function, which should be altering the entries of the matrix, don't!

Remove semicolon `;` from the end of your function `matrix_gen`

```
void matrix_gen(......, int opt_strat[m][m][m]);
                                               ^Remove this semicolon
```

Despite of this, there are too many problems with your code. You have to fix them all.

Comment: ..I don't know why that was there. I think that was just a keyboard fudge or something, since it's not in the main code (and as I tried, it wouldn't have even compiled if it were there)

Uh, what other problems are there?

Comment: To figure out all the problems, I have to review your entire code. It would take some time to fix them but I am busy with my semester exams and I do not have much time to do so. Hope someone will answer your question. Best of luck :)